# при подключении БД SQLite к Активити не виден класс

Tags: java, android, sqlite

создан класс `TestDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper`. В `MainActivity` в методе `onCreate()` делается попытка создания объекта этого класса, но Андроид студия ругается, что не видит этого класса и предлагает создать. почему так происходит?
вот кусок кода класса `TestDataBaseHelper`:

```
public class TestDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "test.db";

    TestDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TEST (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+"NAME TEXT);");
        insertTest(db,"Alexandr");
        insertTest(db,"Peter");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }

   private static void insertTest(SQLiteDatabase db, String name){
       ContentValues testValues = new ContentValues();
       testValues.put("NAME", name);
       db.insert("TEST", null, testValues);
   }
}
```

кусок кода `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteOpenHelper testDataBaseHelper = new TestDataBaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = testDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

Comment: Если классы в разных пакетах, добавьте к конструктору класса модификатор public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас класс `TestDataBaseHelper` храниться в другом пакете.
добавьте модификатор к вашему конструктору.

```
    public TestDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
```